# Dúvia match perl

Tags: perl

Preciso de uma ajuda em perl para um match em expressão regular... Porém é o inverso do que geralmente acontece....

Eu preciso fazer um match no seguinte.

Tenho o número "(0003[6-9])|(00041)|:.*:30/30*", o delimitador é o dois pontos, porém, eu precisava testar se um determinado número fará match nessas colunas...  Enfim eu precisava saber se existe uma forma de realizar o teste de um número em uma expressão regular.

Obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi o seu problema. Sim, é possível realizar match por um número específico. Coloque exemplos de textos que você precisa fazer match que posso te ajudar com a Expressão Regular.

Comment: Quero testar se o número 00038 faz match nessa coluna:
(0003[6-9])|(00041)

Porém eu possuo linhas onde contém .* neste arquivo que equivale a uma linha que por ordem de sequencia ele deverá fazer match na primeira ocorrencia, ex:

linha1: .*
linha2: (0003[6-9])|(00041)

Neste caso deverá ocorrer o match na linha 1. Entendeu?

Comment: Não. O `regex` "(0003[6-9])|(00041)" faz match no número 00038 sim: https://regex101.com/r/mN4vZ6/1

Comment: Eu sei que faz..... Mas quando tento comprar no perl se 00038 faz match em (0003[6-9])|(00041) ele retorna vazio.... entendeu? Esse é o problema.... o input é 00038 que deve ser verificado dentro da expressão.

Comment: Agora entendi. Como seu problema é no Perl, coloca trecho do seu código, pode ter alguma coisa errada nele.

Comment: `if ("00038" =~ /(0003[6-9])|(00041)/){ print "faz\n" } ` ?